# Piping python scripts for ETL

Tags: python, pandas, bash

I'm trying to write a bash/batch script that will connect Python scripts for an ETL pipeline.
I have test scripts:

- test1.py:

```
# test1.py 
import pandas as pd
import sys

test_data = [
   {'num_float': 3.14, 'num_int': 6,  'text': 'Hello'},
   {'num_float': 2.71, 'num_int': 28, 'text': 'World'}
]
def main():
    return pd.DataFrame(test_data, columns = ['num_float', 'num_int', 'text'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main().to_csv(sys.stdout)
```

- test2.py

```
# test2.py
import pandas as pd
import sys

def main(df):
   print(df.columns)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.read_csv(sys.stdin.read())
    main(df)
```

Running the command:
`python test1.py | python test2.py`
yields an error:

`OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:',num_float,num_int,text\n\n0,3.14,6,hello\n\n1,2.71,28,world\n\n'`

Does anyone know any suitable workarounds?

Comment: You posted a wrong _test1.py_.

Comment: @Armali Apologies, missing paranthesis.

Comment: There's still another error. Do you type the script in instead of copy and paste it?

Comment: @Armali, apologies - another typo. Sorted now and runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>     df = pd.read_csv(sys.stdin.read())
> ```

`read_csv` takes a *file-like object* (the string you pass is interpreted as a file name), so just write

```
    df = pd.read_csv(sys.stdin)
```